# polarity of dc power require by electronic device

Tags: power, connector

How can the polarity required of device marked 7.5V 1.2A dc be determined, i.e. how to know if the center of the plug on the device's box is positive or negative

I do not have the original charger.

There are no markings of polarity on the case, just the rating

Comment: Can you post a photo of the device's markings please?

Comment: Most things I've seen that require a plug-in "wall wart" DC power supply have a little drawing by the connector showing the correct polarity.

Answer (score 1):

**Usually** the center pin of a Power jack will be + / positive. I say **usually** because there are exceptions, every manufacturer can do as they please.

There is way to confirm the polarity though althoug I cannot guarantee that it will always be 100% correct. But on most devices the shielding of other connectors will be connected to ground. Also many times the metal chassis of the device will be connected to ground. Using a multimeter you can check which pin of the Power jack has the lowest resistance to these ground points. That pin then has a high chance of being the ground pin.

Some devices might have a reverse polarity protection diode. You can also test this with a proper multimeter on diode test. The diode must of course not conduct when power is applied with the proper polarity.

Answer (score 1):

Look for these markings on the adapter.
[image]